# Windows 10 - Make context menu of pinned items compact like win7 one.

Tags: windows, menu

I'd like the windows 10 context menu be more compact like the windows 7 one. It is too space-consuming and fits too few items in it as is.

I do already use classic shell, but I haven't found an option to alter this thing.

[Windows 7 pinned item context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzxls.png)

[Windows 10 pinned item context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JQvt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 tries to be touch friendly and also wants to shove the UWP/Modern/Metro design down your throat so I think you are stuck with it unless you want to upgrade to Windows 7/8.